# Should I rekey new locks before or after installing?

Tags: lock

I'm buying several Schlage smart locks for my house. I'm gonna buy one to make sure it fits on all my doors and then buy the rest.

Is it better or cheaper to these rekeyed before installing them?

Comment: I always take cylinders out of the lock assemblies and take them to the locksmith.  The more the locksmith does the more you pay, the less the locksmith does the less you pay.

Answer (score 3):

If you're going to re-key the locks yourself, it shouldn't matter.

If you need to have a locksmith do it, you'll save yourself paying for a service call if you can take the locks to the locksmith before you install them in the doors.